# Docker : OCI runtime create failed: executable file not found in $PATH

Tags: docker

The error message I am getting while running the container:

> Docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed:
>   container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec:
>   \"mkdir NNEEWW\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown

My Dockerfile:

> FROM python:3
>
> COPY . /
>
> RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r /requirements.txt
>
> EXPOSE 5678
>
> CMD ["mkdir NNEEWW", "&", "jupyter", "notebook", "--ip=0.0.0.0",
>   "--port=5678", "--allow-root"]

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract `"mkdir NNEEWW", "&"*` outside the CMD as in docker CMD is used to run the executable, you can anyway create a new folder before the CMD command if you need by using the command `RUN mkdir NNEEWW`.